# Python - efficiently check a list exists AND element exists in list

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a variable `foo`, which points to a string, `"bar"`

```
foo = "bar"
```

I have a list, called `whitelist`.
If `whitelist` is not empty, the elements contained are a whitelist.
If `whitelist` is empty, then the if statement permits any string.

I have implemented this as follows

```
whitelist = ["bar", "baz", "x", "y"]

if whitelist and foo in whitelist:
    print("bar is whitelisted")
    # do something with whitelisted element
```

`if whitelist`, by my understanding, checks if `whitelist` returns `True`. whitelist will be `False` if whitelist is empty. If `whitelist` contains elements, it will return `True`.

However, the real implementation of this contains:

- lots of strings to check e.g. `"bar", "baz", "x", "y", "a", "b"
- lots of whitelists to check against

Therefore, **I was wondering if there is a more computationally efficient way of writing the if statement**. It seems like checking the existence of whitelist each time is inefficient, and could be simplified.

Comment: Try `if foo in whitelist:` instead, then you are evaluating if the string is in the list.

Comment: Use a dict instead of a list of your whitelist is large.  I mean, it would be, otherwise why would you care about performance.  Why are you checking if whitelist exists?  What value is whitelist if doesn't "exist"?  I would coerce it `whitelist = whitelist or []`

Comment: You could try NumPy which is computationally efficient like this `np.core.defchararray.find(bar,foo)!=-1`. For this, to work, you need to make a whitelist an `np` array. You will need to check if whitelist is empty or not like this `if whitelist.size == 0:`

Comment: With all things performance, measure before you fix anything, and measure your fix to ensure it helps.  Copying a large array to a dict or NumPy array may be  more expensive than a 1000 searches.

Comment: Also, if you do `n` tests, consider collecting all your `foos` in a set, and make whitelist a set then use `foos & whitelist` (intersection)  to figure which `foos` are in your `whitelist`.  Should be roughly `len(foos)` and faster then `len(foos)` separate lookups.

Answer (score 2):

These are some ways to check whether an element is in a list or not.

```py
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np




whitelist1 = {"bar", "baz", "x", "y"}
whitelist2 = np.array(["bar", "baz", "x", "y"])

def func1():
    return {"foo"}.intersection(whitelist1)

def func2():
    return "foo" in whitelist1

def func3():
    return np.isin('foo',whitelist1)


def func4():
    return whitelist2[np.searchsorted(whitelist2, 'foo')] == 'foo'




print("func1=",timeit(func1,number=100000))
print("func2=",timeit(func2,number=100000))
print("func3",timeit(func3,number=100000))
print("func4=",timeit(func4,number=100000))
```

Time Taken by each function

```
func1= 0.01365450001321733
func2= 0.005112499929964542
func3 0.5342871999600902
func4= 0.17057700001168996
```

---

##### FOr randomly generated list

```
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np
import random as rn
from string import ascii_letters


# randomLst = for a in range(500) rn.choices(ascii_letters,k=5)

randomLst = []
while len(randomLst) !=1000:
    radomWord = ''.join(rn.choices(ascii_letters,k=5))
    if radomWord not in randomLst:
        randomLst.append(radomWord)


whitelist1 = {*randomLst}
whitelist2 = np.array(randomLst)
randomWord = rn.choice(randomLst)
randomWords = set(rn.choices(randomLst, k=100))


def func1():
    return {randomWord}.intersection(whitelist1)

def func2():
    return randomWord in whitelist1

def func3():
    return np.isin('foo',whitelist1)


def func4():
    return whitelist2[np.searchsorted(whitelist2, randomWord)] == randomWord


def func5():
    return randomWords & whitelist1

print("func1=",timeit(func1,number=100000))
print("func2=",timeit(func2,number=100000))
print("func3",timeit(func3,number=100000))
print("func4=",timeit(func4,number=100000))
print("func5=",timeit(func5,number=1000)) # Here I change the number to 1000 because we check the 100 randoms word at one so number = 100000/100 = 1000.
```

Time taken

```
func1= 0.012835499946959317
func2= 0.005004600039683282
func3 0.5219665999757126
func4= 0.19900090002920479
func5= 0.0019264000002294779
```

#### Conclusion

1. If you want to check only one word then 'in' statement is fast
2. But, if you have a list of word then '&' statement is fast 'func5'

Note: function 5 returns a set with the words that are in the whitelist

Comment: Good answer but it's highly sensitive to number of lookups and len(whitelist).  So not sure if it really answers anything but it's a good framework for op to evaluate.  You should add a case where whitelist is already a set (perhaps instead of func1?)

Comment: If you want to be fancy, randomly generating whitelist of size `n`, then generate `m * p` samples from whitelist and `m * (1 -p)` not in whitelist.  Now you outsources most if not all of assumptions of the data.  If you do it, I am curious what the two set intersects yield opposed to 100k individual lookups.

Comment: Eliminate the print as it adds noise in your measurement, so just `def func1(): return {"foo"}.intersection(whitelist1)`.

Comment: https://kudadam.com/blog/random-words-python

Comment: I did the intersect of two sets and it's fastest.  func5= 4.349200753495097e-05 vs func2= 0.005254118994344026: `print("func5=", timeit(func5, number=1))` and `func5(): return randomWords & whitelist1`.    `print("func5=", timeit(func5, number=1))`

Comment: @AllanWind But on my side in statement is always fastest,

Comment: Check this https://onlinegdb.com/MoIH8mELl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247977/discussion-between-codester-09-and-allan-wind).

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/M_teO2sGc

Comment: You may still be right if you count the time to build the randomWords set (we don't know if it should or not).  Thanks for being awesome with the revised code.

Comment: @AllanWind I will add your solution also I forget it.

Answer (score 1):

`whitelist` would exist, but if it's possible `None` coerce with:

```
whitelist = whitelist or []
```

As shared above then you can just `foo in whitelist` to figure out if it's in the list.  This is `O(len(whitelist))` operation.  Arrays are surprisingly fast (say, for at least `len(whitelist) >= 1,000`) in practice.

If you need it to be faster use a set, and optionally if you need to do `n` lookup collect your foos into a set then use intersect for `O(n)`:

```
foos = { 'bar', 'none' }
whitelist = { 'bar' }
for foo in foos & whitelist:
   print(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplified solution, You can do that with two methods

```
whitelist = ["bar", "baz", "x", "y"]
foo = "bar"
# method 1
def WhiteListExists(foo, whitelist):
    if whitelist and foo in whitelist:
        return True
    else:
        return False

exists = WhiteListExists(foo,whitelist)

# method 2
exists = True if whitelist and foo in whitelist else False
```

Both methods do the same but the second one is fast.

Comment: Is there any difference between this and direct return `whitelist and foo in whitelist`?

Comment: The difference is 1st method is using python functions and 2nd method uses python comprehensions